# Selecting NA values from sql file in R

Tags: sql, r

I have sql tables being read in R with the following code

```
library(RSQLite)

setwd("C:/Users/Cat/Downloads")
drv = dbDriver("SQLite")
# Use the driver to connect to a particular sqlite database file
con = dbConnect(drv, "cartype")

dbListTables(con)
```

And there are columns named as ID and credit in a table Sale. Some of the credit is missing and I can select them with the following code.

```
wow = dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Sale WHERE
                 credit IS NOT \"NA\";')
```

Question is how can I select ID with Date is NA? I tried the code

```
wow = dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Sale WHERE
                 credit IS \"NA\";')
```

OR

```
wow = dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Sale WHERE
                 credit == \"NA\";')
```

The codes work but giving a incorrect result that there's 0 result matching the condition, while it should have more than 100 IDs with NA credit.

Can anyone help me out, and show me how can I get IDs with NA credit?
Thanks !

Comment: You know your data so you may have "NA" values stored, but generally when checking for missings in databases I use `NULL` e.g. `select * from Sale where credit IS NULL`.  Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: Thanks, using NULL instead of \"NA\" works. But now I realized my first code wow = .... actually contained one NA in the result while the code `select*from Sale where credit IS NULL` also contained one NA in the result. Why would this happened ?

Comment: what datatype is sale.credit?

Comment: it is text. For those have credit records would be a person name.

Comment: in that case you will want something like `where credit <> \"NA\" and credit is not null` to do both conditions

Comment: I tried the code you just gave but there's still one NA in the result. And the code seems to be selecting ID with credit rather than ID with NULL credit? 
Also, do you mind explain a bit on the code with <>\"NA\" ? What does that means? Thanks so much !!

Comment: ah sorry - wrong way round `where credit = \"NA\" or credit is null` will get you any NA values and anything missing.  `<>` is another not equals operator, along with `!=`

Comment: hmm, there's still a NA in the result....:( Just to confirm, you mean I should try the code `hey = dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Sale WHERE credit = \"NA\" OR credit IS NULL;')` right? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need the NA result, remove the section `credit = \"NA\" OR`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42411/discussion-between-user2978129-and-steph-locke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're coming up against a mis-aprehension about how missings are stored in databases.  These are usually stored as NULLs as opposed to NA.

Your first statement works because it is comparing a column of some type (e.g. date, int, varchar) against a string ("NA") and this will exclude NULLs because a string comparison (whether implicit or explicit) will always exclude missings and since all your dates will be different to "NA" it will return all non-missing records.

The reason why your second and third statements go onto return 0 records is because it is again doing a string comparison which will exclude NULLs and also won't find a match.

For SQLite, there is a great page on how NULLs are handled which might help you out with more detail on this topic: http://sqlite.org/nulls.html